# Cucumber features don't play well together, based on type of user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cucumber, integration-testing, activeadmin

SOLVED:  The original author at one point memoized with a f@#$ing class variable.

```
@@roles ||= Role.all
```

Parents, talk to your kids about class variables in ruby.  Before someone else does.

EDIT:  Added scenario and code for the user-creation step.

I'm working on getting an old legacy codebase tested, running into problems when working with cucumber.

In the system there are 'patient', 'site' and 'admin' users.  Some tests require that you be logged in with a patient, others with site, admin, etc.  When I run only the features with a signed in patient, they all work.  When I run only the features with a signed in site user, they all work.  When I run only the features with a signed in admin, they all work.  When I try to run a mix of features with multiple types of users, the features with the second and third type of user do not work.

A clue that I've found is that it seems to treat all users as the type of the user that logged in first in the test run.

Here's a sample test for an site user

```
  Background:
    Given that I am an "site" user

  Scenario: Patients compliance report page
    When I have patient "Joel" with "4" missed days in diary
    And I go to compliance report page
    Then I should see "Patient Compliance Report"
    And I should see columns
      | Site #/Investigator |
      | Patient             |
      | Registration Date   |
      | Compliance %        |
```

The background step calls the following method:

```
def create_and_login_as_role(role)
  role_sym = :"#{role}_user"
  diary = FactoryGirl.create :diary
  study = FactoryGirl.create :study
  site = FactoryGirl.create :site, study: study
  user = FactoryGirl.create role_sym, diary: diary, organization: site
  login user.username, DEFAULT_PASSWORD
end

def login(username, password)
  visit destroy_user_session_path # kills any session, then defaults to login
  fill_in 'user[username]', with: username
  fill_in 'user[password]', with: password

  click_on "Sign in"
end
```

Here's a second scenario

```
Background:
  Given there are two countries
  And there is a region
  Given that I am an "admin" user
  #I have to create 'ted' second because of the stupid hold-on-to-first-user-type bug
  And there is a site user "ted"

Scenario: Creating a site user
  And I visit the "sites" page
  And I click "New Site"
  And I select the first study from the list
  And I select "USA" from "Country"
  And I select "North America" from "Region"
  And I fill in "Site Number" with "234"
  And I fill in "Site Name" with "SiteySiteful"
  And I select "Active" from "Status"
  And I select "ted" from "Investigator"
  And I select "ted" from "Primary Contact"
  And I fill in "password" with "password"
  And I click "Create Site"
  Then I should see "Site was successfully created"
```

In this case, there's a second manifestation of the bug.  If I created the site user first (it's simply a call to a factory), it logged in the admin user as a site user.

Here's the factory for a user:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
factory :user do |u|
  sequence(:email) {|n| "example#{n}@verdacom.com" }
  sequence(:username) {|n| "user#{n}"}
  password "password"
  tmp_password "password"
  country_id 1
  user_state { FactoryGirl.create(:user_state) }
  password_confirmation {|u| u.password}
  first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
  last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
  work_phone "0123456789"
  mobile_phone "0123456789"
  timezone "Etc/UTC"
  diary_creation true
  diary { FactoryGirl.create(:diary) }
end

factory :admin_user, :parent => :user, :class => User do |s|
  sequence(:email) {|n| "admin#{n}@verdacom.com" }
  sequence(:username) {|n| "admin#{n}"}
  force_update_password false
  roles { [FactoryGirl.create(:admin_role)] }
end

factory :diary_author, :parent => :user, :class => User do |s|
  diary nil
end

factory :subject_user, :parent => :user, :class => User do |s|
  roles {[FactoryGirl.create(:subject_role)]}
  diary {FactoryGirl.create(:diary_with_registration_entry)}
  # s.organization { |user| user.association :site }
end

factory :site_user, :parent => :user, :class => User do
  sequence(:email) {|n| "site#{n}@verdacom.com" }
  sequence(:username) {|n| "site#{n}"}
  force_update_password false
  roles { [FactoryGirl.create(:site_role)] }
  # organization { |user| user.association :site }
end
end
```

Here's my gemfile; of note are rails 3.1.5, devise, mysql2, activeadmin custom fork (not my choice), cancan, guard, cucumber_rails, and database_cleaner

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.5'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'activeadmin', :path => "vendor/gems/activeadmin-0.3.4", :git => "https://github.com/alexey/active_admin.git", :branch => "0.3.4-stable" #
gem "haml"
gem "rake", ">= 0.9.2"
gem "meta_search", '>= 1.1.0.pre'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'twiliolib'
gem 'paper_trail'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'capistrano'
gem "capistrano-ext"
gem 'seed-fu', '~> 2.1.0'
gem "timezone"
gem "twilio-ruby"
gem "yettings"
gem "zipruby"
gem "whenever", :require => false
gem "newrelic_rpm"
gem "rabl"
gem 'andand'


gem "execjs"
gem "therubyracer"

gem "hoptoad_notifier", '2.3.11'

gem "faker" # need in development and production/staging also


gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'

group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'turn', '< 0.8.3'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem "timecop" # for time travelling to test "entries" timeframe
  gem "rack-test"
  gem "prawn"   # for pdf test report generation
  gem "webrat" # simulte http interaction with remote service
end

group :test, :development do
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.6"
  gem "shoulda"
  gem "simplecov" # rcov not supported in ruby 1.9

  gem 'capybara-webkit' # for headless testing
  gem 'database_cleaner'

  gem 'debugger'

  gem 'rb-fsevent'
  gem 'spork', '~> 1.0rc'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-cucumber'
  gem 'single_test'
end


group :development do
  gem 'rails-footnotes', '>= 3.7.5.rc4'
  gem "rails-erd"
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'redcarpet'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
end

platforms :ruby do
  gem 'rb-readline'
end
```

Here's my database_cleaner setup for cucumber, which is exactly what's on their github readme:

```
begin
  require 'database_cleaner'
  require 'database_cleaner/cucumber'
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
rescue NameError
  raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish to use it."
end

Before do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

 After do |scenario|
   DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Please ask for any files that might be relevant.

Comment: Do you have any `Background:` steps in any of your scenarios? It sounds like the necessary user type isn't being logged in before each test. To say it another way, I don't think the problem is going to be in your gems for cucumber config. Check the scenarios first, and post whatever `Background:` steps related to login that there are, if any, and/or post the steps that perform login on a per-test basis.

Comment: Do I understand you? You have scenarios tagged with user using which they are run.

Comment: @normalocity, thanks for the suggestions.  I added one feature, including the background step, as well as the relevant code that it calls.

Comment: @AndreyBotalov, yes, for each feature there is a user logged in during the 'background' step, which is used in each scenario.  When I mark several features to be run at the same time with guard, it will keep the user type of the user that was logged in for the feature that was run first, even if the current feature is supposed to log in a different type.

Comment: I also added a second feature in which a second manifestation of the bug surfaces (forgive all the delayed info; I'm a stackoverflow noob, still learning what to include).  

This second manifestation makes clear that you don't necessarily have to log in for the system to latch onto the user type, you just have to create a user with a factory. (speaking of which, I'm going to now add the user factory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:  The original author at one point memoized with a f@#$ing class variable.

```
@@roles ||= Role.all
```

Of course, database cleaner doesn't reset class variables because who the f@#$ uses class variables in ruby?

Parents, talk to your kids about class variables in ruby.  Before someone else does.